# Type.GetCustomAttributesData() not defined in .NET Core

Tags: reflection, .net-core, system.reflection

What is the new equivalent for `Type.GetCustomAttributesData()` in .NET Core?

I can't access this method when porting a project from .Net Framework. It doesn't become available with any of the Reflection NuGets.

Comment: Using GetCustomAttributes gives me `Attribute` types instead of `CustomAttributeData` types - this type still seems to be defined in .NET Core, but I can't find where to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned into `Type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.CustomAttributes`. One would see this and think it is a property that, similar to `GetCustomAttributes()` returns `IEnumerable<Attribute>`, but it returns `IEnumerable<CustomAttributeData>`.

Answer (score 0):

According the `APIsOf.Net`, [`MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Reflection.MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributesData()) method will be available in .Net Core 2.0, assembly `System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`

For now you can try the [`MemberInfo.CustomAttributes`](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Reflection.MemberInfo.CustomAttributes) property in assembly `System.Reflection, Version=4.1.0.0, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`

Comment: Link is not secure. Thanks for the help though. I found what I needed through the .NET Core github PR involving the System.Reflection port.

Comment: What link is insecure? Both of them are https…

Comment: APIsOf.Net -> Chrome tells me not to use it

Comment: Did you click on the link I've provided? First one is: https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Reflection.MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributesData() Second is https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Reflection.MemberInfo.CustomAttributes

Comment: @Dagrooms and, if you type in `https://APIsOf.Net`, you would be able to open it in Chrome